# Having problem w/ matrices on Tensorflows CNN layers

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using an existing neural network (SimpleHTR on github)
So far I tried to play with a CNN layers by adding next ones ( by adding next values in the kernelVals, featureVals and strideVals matrices).

This time I wanted to add kernels only, not whole layers. I tried to do so by adding conv2, conv_norm2, and relu2 within the 'for' loop but an error on matrices size occured.

Im am new to the topic, could someone please explain how do I add kernels within the layer?

```
  def setupCNN(self):
    "create CNN layers and return output of these layers"
    cnnIn4d = tf.expand_dims(input=self.inputImgs, axis=3)

    # list of parameters for the layers
    kernelVals = [5, 5, 3, 3, 3]
    featureVals = [1, 32, 64, 128, 128, 256]
    strideVals = poolVals = [(2,2), (2,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]
    numLayers = len(strideVals)

    # create layers
    pool = cnnIn4d # input to first CNN layer
    for i in range(numLayers):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([kernelVals[i], kernelVals[i], featureVals[i], featureVals[i + 1]], stddev=0.1))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool, kernel, padding='SAME',  strides=(1,1,1,1))
        conv_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=self.is_train)
        relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_norm)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(relu, (1, poolVals[i][0], poolVals[i][1], 1), (1, strideVals[i][0], strideVals[i][1], 1), 'VALID')

    self.cnnOut4d = pool
```

Comment: have you considered using the keras API of tensorflow?

Comment: Can you please explain your statement and clarify your requirement - "This time I wanted to add kernels only, not whole layers. I tried to do so by adding conv2, conv_norm2, and relu2 within the 'for' loop but an error on matrices size occured." By using conv2, conv_norm2, and relu2, you are creating a layer, but your statement contradicts not to create a whole layer.

Answer (score 0):

A **kernel** (`extract certain features from an input image`) is a **matrix of weights** which are multiplied with the input to extract relevant features.  Please watch this action in below

[image]

For example, the kernel used above is useful for sharpening the image. But what is so special about this kernel? Consider the two input image arrangements as shown in the example below. For the first image, the center value is 3*5 + 2*-1 + 2*-1 + 2*-1 + 2*-1 = 7. The value 3 got increased to 7. For the second image, the output is 1*5+ 2*-1 + 2*-1 + 2*-1 + 2*-1 = -3. The value 1 got decreased to -3. Clearly, the contrast between 3 and 1 is increased to 7 and -3, which will in turn sharpen the image.

[image]

so to answer your question, **how do I add kernels within the layer ?**

Instead of using manually made kernels for feature extraction, through CNN we can learn these kernel values which can extract latent features.

The dimensions of the kernel matrix is *how the convolution gets it’s name*. For example, in `2D convolutions`, the kernel matrix is a `2D matrix`.

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130836/convert-functional-model-to-sequential-keras/61185389#61185389) to create models in keras through `sequential` and `Functional` mode.